Web camera zoom in/zoom out
I want to add zoom-in/zoom-out logic for my web camera, with this version it works only via input onChange, but I need to remove the input...do you have a suggestion on how can I make it without input? It doesn't work not in useEffect and not even on button onClick.
 const handleZoomChange = useCallback(
            async (zoomValue: number) => {
                // @ts-ignore
                const video = ref.current;
                if (video && video.srcObject) {
                    const videoTracks = video.srcObject.getVideoTracks();
                    if (videoTracks.length > 0) {
                        const track = videoTracks[0];
                        const constraints = { advanced: [{ zoom: zoomValue }] };
                        try {
                            await track.applyConstraints(constraints);
                        } catch (error) {
                            console.error('Failed to apply constraints:', error);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            [ref]
        );
        const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            const value = e.target.value;
            setInputZoom(value);
            if (value !== '') {
                const zoomValue = Math.max(1, Number(value));
                handleZoomChange(zoomValue);
            }
        };
                         <input
                            type="number"
                            min={1}
                            value={inputZoom}
                            onChange={handleInputChange}
                        />

